# How can I check If the valid page was loaded in the WKWebView?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

**That's what I'm doing:**

1. Loading the page in WKWebView
2. Pressing the button on the page

As a result I can get either valid URL, either invalid URL. How do I check if I've got the valid one? I need something like `URLThatWasLoadedInWKWebView == "myValidURL"`?

```
var webView: WKWebView!
var webUrl="google.com"

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let url = URL(string: webUrl)!
  let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
  webView.load(urlRequest)
  view.insertSubview(webView, at: 0)
}
```

After I clicked on the button, I need to check that the page has loaded the valid "mail.google.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your view controller conform to the `WKNavigationDelegate` then you can use those delegate functions to get the information you're looking for.

Inside this delegate function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

You could check the `webView.url` which shows you the url that the web view just loaded. You could use that to check against whatever url you are trying to check against.

Comment: `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`


Will this function allow me to compare the current URL (which was just loaded in WKWebView) with the valid URL?

Comment: You'll have to post some code to verify. But in order to load a page in the web view you have to call `webView.load(someURLRequst)`

Comment: So its not like the web view is just loading random things you have to verify against. It loads something specific you give it. So then you just check if it was a successful load.

Comment: I changed my question, please check it

Comment: @Андрей-Хышов: Let me know if my revised answer answers your question. If it doesn't, I'm happy to clarify anything, and if it does, can you mark it as the correct answer?